# EF Core completely ignores my selected properties in select

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

As I understand it, the following code should generate a query containing only the `RouteId`, `RouteNo`, and `ShipId`

```
        var tow = (from t in _context.AllTowData
                   where t.RouteId == id
                   orderby t.RouteNo descending
                   select new TowDefaults {
                       Id = t.RouteId,
                       TowNo = t.RouteNo,
                       ShipId = t.ShipId,
                       LastTow = t.RouteNo
                   })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, I get:

```
SELECT v.route_id, v.route_no, v.tow_id, v.analysis_complete, v.checks_complete, v.cpr_id, v.date_created, v.date_last_modified, v.factor, v.fromportname, v.instrument_data_file, v.instrument_id, v.internal_number, v.mastername, v.message, v.miles_per_division, v.month, v.number_of_samples, v.number_of_samples_analysed_fully, v.prop_setting, v.route_status, v.sampled_mileage, v.serial_no_per_calendar_month, v.ship_speed, v.silk_reading_end, v.silk_reading_start, v.toportname, v.tow_mileage, v.validity, v.year
FROM view_all_tow_data AS v
WHERE v.route_id = '@__id_0'
ORDER BY v.route_no DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That's every column **except** the explicitly requested `ShipId`! What am I doing wrong?

This happens using both a SQL Server and a PostGres database

Comment: What is the *exact* type of `AllTowData`? Also, you should show the class model + custom mapping code, if present.

Comment: This usually happens when you include some unmapped (`[NotMappped]` or `.Ignore(...)`d) source column in the `Select`.  Looks like in this case `ShipId` is the property configured to be ignored.

Comment: Select into an anonymous type ```.Select(t => new { t.RouteId, TowNo = t.RoueNo })```;

Comment: @BjarkeHandsdal I can't see how an anonymous type would help, but … it didn't :-( I had tried that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `ShipId`is not mapped, either by a `[NotMapped]` annotation or a mapping instruction. As far as EF is concerned, the property doesn't exist. This has two effects:

1. EF "notices" that there's an unknown part the final `Select` and it switches to client-side evaluation (because it's a final `Select`). Which means: it translates the query before the `Select` into SQL which doesn't contain the `ShipId` column, executes it, and materializes full `AllTowData` entities.
2. It evaluates the `Select` client-side and returns the requested `TowDefaults` objects in which `ShipId` has its default value, or any value you initialize in C# code, but nothing from the database.

You can verify this by checking `_context.AllTowData.Local` after the query: it will contain all `AllTowData` entities that pass the filter.

From your question it's impossible to tell what you should do. Maybe you can map the property to a column in the view. If not, you should remove it from the LINQ query. Using it in LINQ anywhere but in a final `Select` will cause a runtime exception.

Comment: Oh, ****, I checked this half a million times [maybe not _quite_ that much], and EVEN posted the model in the question, and **still** didn't see the `[Not Mapped]` until it appeared in the question. Never mind...